# Why Python properties require helper functions with the same name?

Tags: python, properties, overloading

In the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) explaining properties, it is said:

> Be sure to give the additional functions the same name as the original property (x in this case.)

I.e., the getter, setter and deleter methods must all have the same name.

Why? And also, Python forbids method overloading, doesn't it?

EDIT:
Why does the following code fail when run in Python 2.6?

```
class Widget(object):
    def __init__(self, thing):
        self.thing = thing
        print self.thing

    @property
    def thing(self):
        return self._thing

    @thing.setter
    def set_thing(self, value):
        self._thing = value


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Widget('Some nonsense here')
```

Its output is:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   
 File "widget.py", line 16, in <module>
     Widget('Some nonsense here')     
 File "widget.py", line 3, in __init__
     self.thing = thing 
 AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

The code works fine when set_thing() is renamed to thing().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python does indeed not feature method overloading, but you're correct that the docs encourage you to name the getters and setters identically, and demonstrates it to boot.  What's going on here?

The trick is to understand how method decorators work in Python.  Whenever you see something like this:

```
@foo
def bar():
    frob()
    quux()
```

what Python actually does under the covers is to rewrite it this way:

```
def bar():
    frob()
    quux()
bar = foo(bar)
```

In other words: define a function `bar`, then replace it with the result of calling `foo` *on the bar function*.

While that's all true, the order of evaluation is actually slightly different than the above when it comes to how names are resolved.  It might be easier for you to pretend for a moment that what actually happens looks a bit closer to this:

```
def __secret_internal_function_name__():
    frob()
    quux()
bar = foo(__secret_internal_function_name__)
```

Why does this matter?  Let's look at the Python in that documentation link:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        self._x = value

    @x.deleter
    def x(self):
        del self._x
```

Let's rewrite this using what we now know to understand what Python is actually doing:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    def __secret_x_prop__(self):
        """I'm the 'x' property."""
        return self._x
    x = property(__secret_x_prop__)

    def __secret_x_setter__(self, value):
        self._x = value
    x = x.setter(__secret_x_setter__)

    def __secret_x_getter__(self):
        del self._x
    x = x.deleter(__secret_x_getter__)
```

Now, we can actually see what's going on: we're not overloading functions; we're gradually building up a `property` object that references other functions.

It's also worth noting that, depending on how you create the property, the names don't need to match.  Specifically, if you create the property explicitly with the `property` function, as is done in the first example in the documentation, the names can be whatever you want; the example has them called `getx`, `setx`, and `delx`, and it works fine.  In what I assume is a safety precaution, `property.setter`, `property.deleter`, and the like *do* require the function passed have the same name, but they're doing the same thing behind the scenes as the more explicit `property` example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, but please see my edit. The reason I posted the question was because I ran into an error, as shown above.

Comment: Got it.  Updated my response appropriately: if you create the property with `property` the whole way, like in the first doc example, the names don't matter, but they clearly do if you use `property.setter` and the other decorators.  There's no technical reason for that; it's simply defined that way.

Comment: Ok, I will wait some time before selecting an answer to see if someone knows this detail. Anyway, I really like what you wrote.

Answer (score 1):

> In the docs explaining properties, it is said:

Incorrect. That is documentation explaining **using the property name as part of a decorator**. When creating properties in the "classic" way, the methods can have any name desired.

And since the decorator is intercepting the method creation, there is no overloading.